# Why is the existing content removed when I appendChild to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create an implementation of "infinite scrolling".  Here is my relevant code:

```
var postsIndex = 0;
var chunk = 5;

function getNextChunk() {
    for (i=0; i<chunk; i++) {
        postsIndex++;
        document.write(getTimeLineElement(posts[postsIndex]));
    }
}

if (postsIndex === 0) {  // initial chunk.
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("DIV"); // Create the div container.
    var divTextNode = document.createTextNode(getNextChunk()); // Create a text node with the initial chunk.
    contentDiv.appendChild(divTextNode); // Append the text node to the div container.
    contentDiv.style.border="solid";
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        alert("near bottom!");
        contentDiv.appendChild(getNextChunk());
    }
});
```

The initial chunk loads just fine and the loading of the 2nd chunk is triggered just fine. However, when the 2nd chunk gets loaded the original content is lost leaving only what was appended.  As you can see I have placed a border around the div for testing purposes.  I'm not seeing that border.  I'm not sure why. This may be an indication that somehow this whole thing is not in the div element like I think that it is.  Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks for any input.

... doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function, `getNextChunk`, which is called at various times after the document has loaded, itself calls `document.write`. As described in the [notes in MDN's `document.write` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write#Notes), when called against a document that has loaded, `document.write` makes an implicit call to `document.open`. The [Notes in the MDN documentation for `document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes) state that when called against an existing document, `document.open` clears that document.

As such, your function is wiping out the document before inserting your content.

I don't know what you expect any of this to do anyway...you're calling `appendChild` while passing in a function call. This means that function's return value would be passed in--but it doesn't return anything...*and* it calls `document.write` in a loop...it's really all over the map.

Comment: Thanks.  Your comment re document.write answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

We will start with the line that is not behaving the way you expect.

```
contentDiv.appendChild(getNextChunk());
```

What does this mean?

It means, execute the `getNextChunk` function and *whatever it returns*, add it to the DOM as a child of `contentDiv`.

So, what does `getNextChunk` return?

```
function getNextChunk() {
    for (i=0; i<chunk; i++) {
        postsIndex++;
        document.write(getTimeLineElement(posts[postsIndex]));
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from that code, it does not actually return anything.  Therefore, you are adding *nothing* as a child of your content div.

So what is getting added to the DOM?

You are calling `getTimeLineElement`, but adding its return value (assuming it is a string) directly to the HTML content of the page.  This does not go into the div, but just gets appended to the document.

What did I do wrong?

- Returns: You are passing the return value of a function which does not return anything.
- Side effects: You have a function named `get*`, which suggests it exclusively reads data, but actually mutates the page (called a side effect).
- Data types: The result of a function named `getTimeLineElement`, which suggests it returns a DOM element, actually returns a string.

Always understand what data types you are working with and how they move around from function to function.